# Using GL_SRC1_COLOR in glBlendFunc()

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, blending, color-blending

I am using glBindFragDataLocationIndexed() and writing two colors in fragment shader. Following is my code :

```
glBindFragDataLocationIndexed(shader_data.psId, 0, 0, "Frag_Out_Color0");
glBindFragDataLocationIndexed(shader_data.psId, 0, 1, "Frag_Out_Color1");

glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE0 );
LoadTexture(texture1);    
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id1);
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture1_data);

glActiveTexture ( GL_TEXTURE1 );
LoadTexture(texture2);
glBindTexture ( GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex_id2);
glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA,width, height, 0, GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture2_data);


glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_SRC1_COLOR);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
```

Fragment Shader is :

```
#version 150
in vec2 texcoord;

uniform sampler2D basetexture1;
uniform sampler2D basetexture2;

out vec4 Frag_Out_Color0;
out vec4 Frag_Out_Color1;

void main(void)
{
    Frag_Out_Color0 = texture2D(basetexture1, texcoord);

    Frag_Out_Color1 = texture2D(basetexture2, texcoord);

}
```

OGL3.3 spec says that :

```
Data written to the ﬁrst of these outputs becomes the ﬁrst source
color input to the blender (corresponding to SRC_COLOR and SRC_ALPHA). Data
written to the second of these outputs generates the second source color input to
the blender (corresponding to SRC1_COLOR and SRC1_ALPHA).
```

I have passed GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_SRC1_COLOR as inputs to glBlendFunc(). I am not sure whether the result is correct or not. Please find attached images. Also if I pass GL_ONE,GL_ONE ,only first texture is rendered and no sign of second texture at all.
How can I verify that rest of my code is fine (and blending is correctly done) ?

Following are texture 1 , texture 2 and result respectively.

[image: Texture 1] [image: Texture 2] [image: Result]

Comment: http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your result is what you would expect, assuming that the destination color is black. It's not clear what exactly you intend `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_SRC1_COLOR);` to do. But what it will do is [what blending *always* does](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Blend_Equations).

The source factor (`GL_SRC_COLOR`) will be multiplied by the source color (or, to be more precise, the source0 color). The destination factor (`GL_SRC1_COLOR`) will be multiplied by the destination color. The results of these multiplications will be added together.

In your case, this means that the source0 color will be multiplied by *itself* (therefore making the result darker). The destination color will be multiplied by the source1 color; if the destination is zero, you get 0. Therefore, you get the source0 color multiplied by itself as the output.

[Dual source blending](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Dual_Source_Blending) is only *useful* (in that it's something you couldn't do in your shader) if you need to perform some operation between the two source colors and the *destination* color. If it can be expressed as `(Src0 op Src1) op Dest`, then it's stuff you should do in your shader.

Comment: So if I pass (GL_ONE,GL_ZERO) and (GL_ZERO,GL_ONE) to glBlendFunc() I should get two different textures as output that were passed as inputs (source0 and source1). But that doesn't happen. (GL_ZERO,GL_ONE) gives me no output at all (black screen) and (GL_ONE,GL_ZERO) gives me first texture as output.
So I think something is wrong with code since source 1 is incorrect.

Comment: @maverick9888: No. The source *factor* is multiplied by the source0 *color*. And the destination *factor* is multiplied by the destination *color*. The factors are your parameters to `glBlendFunc`. You only get to control *part* of the equation; it's always between the source0 and destination colors.

Comment: :(GL_ONE,GL_ZERO) and (GL_ZERO,GL_ONE) seems to generate two textures as I prev said if I use simple blending and not using GL_SRC1_COLOR (i.e use framebuffer contents as destination and new geometry as source).
Are these blending equations different when it comes to (Src0 op Src1) ? Also if I am denoting second color by GL_SRC1_COLOR , what will be the significance of GL_DST_COLOR in glBlendFunc() ?

Comment: @maverick9888: What do you mean by "generate two textures?" You're not generating textures; you're rendering to something. So it's not clear what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that it creates two different outputs which contains textures I am passing to shader.